# How to fix a wrong merge in git?

Tags: git

After a wrong merge all the code-changes of the last day were overwritten. Because it was not noticed, new commits were made on top of the wrong merge. How can I go back to a certain commit and then add the commits that had been made after the wrong merge?

```
git reset or git revert ?
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly the faulty merge happened? Is it just "a not current branch was merged, a more up to date one should be merged"?

Comment: @k0pernikus a developer pulled and somehow stashed all pulled code and then pushed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-write history:

```
git checkout master  // switch to master
git checkout -b fix_it  // create a fix_it branch, and switch to it
git rebase -i <hash_right_before_bad_commit> // cherry-pick all the good commits - leave out the bad one
```

If the fix_it branch looks good, time to reset master so that it points to fix_it:

```
git checkout master
git branch old_master // create an old_master branch in case you want to rollback
git reset fix_it  // now master has the new fixed history (without the bad commit)

// double-check your branches and make sure everything looks ok (and the bad commit is gone from your history)
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate-short

// if everything looks good, push the changes to your remote repository
git push origin master --force // you'll need to force it since you've re-written history

// clean up the tmp branches
git branch -D fix_it, old_master

// inform your team members to force get master (or just to be safe, just re-clone repository).
```

Comment: I dont really think this is a good answer, as rewrtiing history is most of the times a bad idea..

Comment: This was the only solution I was left after I royally screwed up a repository history, and it was the only way I could fix it. Although I can see why it's dangerous, in certain cases it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Show current state**

You can see all branch references by command:

```sh
git branch -a
```

You can see commit history command like this:

```sh
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
```

**Original state**

Very often you have branch references local and origin. Local references is modified by merge operation which you just done.

You have before merge

```
eb686c4 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) some work 1
22abb23 (HEAD -> fix, origin/fix) some work 2
```

**New state**

You have after merge

```
aa183c1 (HEAD -> master) some work 1
bb426c2 some work 2
cc686c4 (origin/master) some work 1
ddabb23 (HEAD -> fix, origin/fix) some work 2
```

**Rollback to origin**

So you can rollback branch to previous by reset branch by command

```sh
# here you are at master (HEAD -> master)
git reset --hard origin/master

# or if you are not at master branch
git branch -f master origin/master
```

**Rollback to preliminary marked state**

It is beter to make temporary branch (I call branch as `m`):

```sh
# create branch m to ref to same commit as current branch (master)
git branch m master
# do merge or rebase
git merge ...
```

Now if you have some problem you can rever master back as it was when branch `m` was created:

```sh
# here you are at master (HEAD -> master)
git reset --hard m

# or if you are not at master branch
git branch -f master m
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case it should suffice to either:

- merge again the correct branch with your missing changes
- revert the merge commit (and only the merge commit) and then merge the current branch that should have been merged in the first place

If on the other hand you are missing some commits because some reverted commits in the past, you may have to revert those revert commit.

git reset only makes sense if you want to force a certain state and push force it on the remote, which can cause trouble on its own. Treat carefully there, yet depending on the repository's state, it could make sense.

Comment: how can I merge again the correct branch with your missing changes? Can I make branch of the previous commit and then merge it with the current branch?